# JQuery confirm delete with onclick issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my confirm alert box script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.confirm').click(function(){
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
        if (answer){
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

My link to get this is

```
 <span class='button-content confirm' onclick= \"location.href='delet-project.php?id={$row['project_id']}';\"
```

The problem is it delete the record.Even i gave cancel.I call the jquery by using the class confirm.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show your html structure of this part.

Comment: where is the delete code?

Comment: The above works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aev7S/

Comment: it is impossible to see the mistake there, but as a comment you can erase that ugly 'if'. if you just replace the if with 'return answer'. think about it is the same

Comment: you must use prevent default in javascript or else you can use a div instead of a link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.confirm').click(function(){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")){
            // your deletion code...
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the same functionality for one of my webistes, where I was making the facebook type conversation system, I am sending the code example from it, please get an idea from my code, (sorry, don't have time to set your parameters in the code, so am sending the original code used in my project).

The javascript function:

```
<script language="javascript">
function ConfirmDelete(id)
{
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this Conversation ?");
    if (result==true)
    {
        window.location = "index.php?page=inbox&delete_conversation="+id;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML, where the title of the conversation is displayed, and an X button is displayed, by clicking on that X button the conversation will be deleted after the confirmation.

```
<h2>
   <a href='javascript:ConfirmDelete(<?php echo $conversation['id']; ?>);'>[x]</a>
   <a href="index.php?page=view_conversation&amp;conversation_id=<?php echo $conversation['id']; ?>"><?php echo $conversation['subject']; ?></a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this One Friend

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#Delete').click(function () {

              var r = confirm("Are you sure want to delete. ");
              if (r == true) {
                  return true;
              }
              else {
                  return false;
              }
          }); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use an anchor in this case:

```
<a class="button-content confirm" href="delet-project.php?id=[project]">click me</a>
```

And then a similar kind of click handler:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.confirm').click(function(e) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```