# PHP Delete Button

Tags: php, mysql, apache, button

I recently started learning PHP on my own and started to use MySQL and Apache as well. I made a basic table in MySQL, and using some PHP code, I displayed the table in a HTML table in a browser. Now I'd like to add a delete button beside each row, and when clicked, it would delete that row. I am very new to this, and I'm just practicing. Could anyone please help me? This is the code I have so far:

---

**From:** [phpcode on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ugwY6a4k)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

mysql_select_db('testdb');

$result = mysql_query('select * from products');

$numrows = mysql_numrows($result);

//****************************************************************
print "<table border = 3 style = width:400px>";


for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

print "<tr>";


foreach($row as $cell)
{

print "<td>";
print $cell;
print "</td>";


}
print "</tr>";


}



print "</table>";


mysql_close();

?>
```

---

I also have a `delete.php` page, but I really don't know where to start. I've looked for online tutorials, and many say different ways.

Comment: Post the code for your delete.php page so far.

Comment: I answered a question on stackoverflow recently,  the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241895/jquery-confirm-delete-with-onclick-issue/22245098#22245098, may benefit you. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another "" inside the loop with delete text and pass the id for that

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

print "<tr>";


foreach($row as $cell)
{

print "<td>";
print $cell;
print "</td>";
print "<td>";
print "DELETE";
print "</td>"; 

}
print "</tr>";


}
```

Comment: Thanks but what you suggested adds "delete" beside every cell. I would like "delete" at the end of the row. And for it to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Let say your table like below;

```
$result = mysql_query('select * from products');

print "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print "<tr><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["surname"] . "</td><td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Here, while iterating your row, you need to put `$row["id"]` in delete link id.

And in your **delete.php**

```
$id = $_GET["id"];

// Delete sql here. Do not forget to validate id here.
header("Location: index.php"); // I assume, table page is this
```

Comment: The reason for a for loop is that if I want to add more rows it does it automatically. You have suggested a manual method. This is what confuses me. I don't know how to do it while using a for loop to print the tr, th etc.

Comment: Just take one copy of row and put it in the loop. In every "td" just pass the values from the database

Comment: @user3464531 you can see my updated answer. I have used iteration and some of your code. You need to use that code according to your need

Answer (score 0):

In your table products you need a field with different value for each register, name it id or whatever you want.

If you have table but doesn't have that field, good option would be and auto_increment field. 
Code for add an auto_increment field:

```
 ALTER TABLE `products` ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```

Then id would be unique for each register and you don't need to worried about it because you don't need to insert it, it is generated automatically.

```
 print "<table border = 3 style = width:400px>";


for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
{
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   print "<tr>";

  foreach($row as $cell)
  {
     print "<td>";
     print $cell;
     print "</td>";
  }
  print "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row["id"] ."' > delete </a> " ;

  print "</tr>";
}
```

$row["id"] is the id of register you want to delete.

in delete.php

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$delete = " DELETE from yourTable where id = ". $id ;

mysq_query ( $delete ) ;
```

PD: Use mysqli_

Comment: I understand your reply the best. I get /delete.php?id= when I click delete though. Where am I supposed to give each row a specific id ie. 1,2,3 etc

Comment: In your bd table add new column, unique for each register, good option would be define an id as a primary key auto_increment

Comment: How would I give a row an id so when I click delete that row deletes. I am completely new to this and am just trying out basics. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Look for the answer's edit. The id for each row is the id for the register in bd and you create it when insert a register to your table.

Comment: I tried everything but I can't seem to get it. This is what I have so far:http://pastebin.com/UEVt6E3R and http://pastebin.com/7vLNq6DY